# Elastic Tabstops in Vim?

Tags: tab-characters

Is there a plugin or a built-in feature in Vim that allows for [elastic tabstops](http://nickgravgaard.com/elastic-tabstops/)? I've searched a bit, and I found some references saying it was not possible in Vim, but those were quite old.

Is there a way to have elastic tabstops in Vim? I am fine with a solution for Neovim as well, as that's what I use anyway.

Comment: There is a [feature request](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/1419) open for this on Neovim.

Answer (score 18):

As far as I can tell there is no reasonable way to accomplish this in a plugin.

There is a [patch](https://github.com/chrisbra/vim-mq-patches/blob/master/var_tabstops) for it, but it's hard to predict when / if the patch will get merged.

Comment: Anybody, if you want this to be merged, please cheer for it at vim-dev (and also reply back how well this works for you)

Comment: This patch doesn't seem to actually be elastic tabstops. Instead it's variable tabstops, but you have to set up the stop points ahead of time. This is nice in its own way but not really what the question is about.

Comment: @Caleb, you could probably script something, once var tabstop patch has been merged.

Comment: @Christian no you couldn't. See the discussion around the web but this can't be done as a script/plugin in vim (even with the variable with tabstop patch) because it only keeps one method to render all lines with. It just doesn't expose what you would need to make this work.

Comment: @Caleb you mean, elastic tabstops means having (potentially) different tabstop settings per line and tabstop?

Comment: @Christian Not probably, that's the whole idea. And ones on adjacent lines will stretch to align with changes on the current (or other modified]s) lines. Read the spec as linked in the question.

Comment: The mentioned patch has been merged as of [8.1.105](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0105)

Answer (score 10):

From the comments: since version 8.1.105, vim has `+vartabs` compile-time feature, thanks to [Christian Brabandt](/users/71/christian-brabandt) !

As far as I can see, this allows implementing elastic tabstops. See [the actual pull request](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/2711).

Comment: You could link to the docs or explain how it could be implemented. That might help future readers more than the link to the user who mentions it.

Comment: :set vartabstop=4,20,10,8 - This will make the first tab 4 spaces wide, the second 20 spaces, the third 10 spaces, and all following tabs 8 spaces.

Comment: vartabstop isn't sufficient for elastic tabstops, because the tabstops can't vary between code blocks. vartabstop applies to the entire file.